# Entity Framework Code First: Refer to same entities twice

Tags: entity-framework, devexpress, code-first, xaf

I has 2 class as below

Contact Class

```
public class Contact : Person
{
    public Contact() { }

    //public string WebPageAddress { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string SpouseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Datejoin { get; set; }

    public double NoOfLeave { get; set; }
    double _totalTake;
    public double TotalTake
    {
        get
        {
            double total = 0;
            if (LeaveTakenDetails != null)
            {
                if (LeaveTakenDetails.Count() > 0)
                {
                    foreach (LeaveTakenDetails leave in LeaveTakenDetails)
                    {
                        total += leave.TotalDayTake;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (total == 0)
            {
                return _totalTake;
            }
            else
            {             
                if(total > _totalTake)
                {
                    return total;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _totalTake;
                }

            }
            //return total;
        }
        set { _totalTake = value; }
    }
    public double RemainLeave { get; set; }

    public TitleOfCourtesy TitleofCourtesy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Anniversary { get; set; }
    [FieldSize(4096)]
    public string Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual Position Position { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<DemoTask> TrackedTasks { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }

    [DataSourceProperty("Department.Contacts", DataSourcePropertyIsNullMode.SelectAll)]
    [DataSourceCriteria("Position.Title = 'Manager'")]
    public virtual Contact Manager { get; set; }


    public virtual IList<LeaveTakenDetails> LeaveTakenDetails { get; set; }
}
public enum TitleOfCourtesy { Dr, Miss, Mr, Mrs, Ms };
```

LeaveTaken Class

```
public class LeaveTakenDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
    public LeaveTakenDetails() { }

    [Key]
    [Browsable(false)]
    public Int32 LeaveID { get; protected set; }

    private double totaltake;
    [Editable(false)]
    [Appearance("LeaveTake", Enabled=false)]
    [ImmediatePostData]
    public double TotalDayTake
    {
        get
        {

        }
        set
        {

        }
    }

    public DateTime Datefrom {
        get；    set;

    }

    public DateTime DateTo
    {
        get;

        set;    
    }
    public virtual LeaveType LeaveType { get; set; }
    public bool AMSession { get; set; }
    public virtual Department Department { get; set; }
    public string Reason { get; set; }
     public DateTime? ApproveDate { get; set; }

    public virtual Contact ApproveBy { get; set; }
    public bool Halfday { get; set; }

    public int Employee_ID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Employee_ID")]
    public virtual Contact Employee { get; set; }

}
```

My ApproveBy and Employee properties is refer to the same Contact class.  When I run the code, the code first will generate the table for me.  When I run the program and try add leave record and select Employee A, and Approve by is Employee C and save the record.  I go to Employee form and look for Employee A, but there is no leave record for Employee A but the leave record added is belong to Employee A.

How I can make the relationship for this?  I feel it is there is two FK in Leave Taken class refer to same Contact class and cause this happen.

Any idea I can see the leave record belong to Employee A in Employee form?
Please help!
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having two foreign key in one table pointing to the same table one is for Employee and one is for Approved by so you will required to have two collections at another end (Contact).

Try like this.

```
public class Contact : Person
{
  ...
  ...
  public virtual IList<LeaveTakenDetails> LeaveApprovalDetails { get; set; }
  public virtual IList<LeaveTakenDetails> LeaveContactDetails { get; set; }
  ...
  ...
}

public class LeaveTakenDetails : INotifyPropertyChanged 
{
  ..
  ..
  public int ApproveBy_ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Contact ApproveBy { get; set; }
  public int Employee_ID { get; set; }
  public virtual Contact Employee { get; set; }
  ..
  ..
}
```

and in Model Creating specify the relation.

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    ...

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
       modelBuilder.Entity<LeaveTakenDetails>()
          .HasRequired(m => m.ApproveBy)
          .WithMany(t => t.LeaveApprovalDetails)
          .HasForeignKey(m => m.ApproveBy_Id)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

       modelBuilder.Entity<Contact>()
          .HasRequired(m => m.Employee)
          .WithMany(t => t.LeaveContactDetails)
          .HasForeignKey(m => m.Employee_Id)
          .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jenish, when I run the add-migration and update-database, it give me an error as below :                                                                                    The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.LeaveTakenDetails_dbo.Parties_ApproveBy_ID". The conflict occurred in database "MainDemo", table "dbo.Parties", column 'ID'.

Comment: @DerickLoo It says there are data conflicts to apply this relationship. for example you specified ApproveBy as required by `HasRequired` method in OnModelCreating method and you are having null data present in your table. so throwing an error.

Comment: Is it possible do not clear off my existing data and perform this?

Comment: I clear off my data and run the add-migration and update database, now it is another error                                                                                  "Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_dbo.LeaveTakenDetails_dbo.Parties_Employee_ID' on table 'LeaveTakenDetails' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints"  What wrong?

Comment: @DerickLoo Updated my answer. you may need to call `.WillCascadeOnDelete(false)` on chain.